# Is total variation distance always achieved?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, total-variation

Given a measurable space ($\Omega$,$\mathcal{F}$) and two probability measures $\mu$, $\nu$.
We define total variation distance as

$$\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert_{TV} = \sup_{A\in \mathcal{F}}|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|.$$

Does it always exist $A\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert_{TV}=|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|$?

If the answer is no, is there a condition such that it is true?

Comment: Consider a Hahn decomposition for $\mu-\nu$.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich. Can you let me know if the following is right just to be sure?
Let $P\in\mathcal{F}$ be the set of the Hahn decomposition and $N=P^c$. Define $\lambda=\mu-\nu$. Let $A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\lambda(A_n)|=\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert_{TV}$. But $|\lambda(A_n)| = |\lambda(A_n\cap P)+\lambda(A_n\cap N)|\leq \max\{|\lambda(P)|,|\lambda(N)|\}$. So, we have $|\mu(P)-\nu(P)|=\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert_{TV}$ or $|\mu(N)-\nu(N)|=\lVert \mu - \nu \rVert_{TV}$.